# SnipMate gVim 7.3 not working

Tags: gvim

I tried to setup gVim 7.3 with SnipMate on Windows 7 64-bit but it doesn't work.

1. I got the latest version from github
2. I copied all files into USER/vimfiles/
3. I put `"filetype plugin on"` into my `_gvimrc`
4. I tried:

   ```
   set runtimepath=$VIMRUNTIME,c:/Users/$USERNAME/vimfiles/after
   ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to change 'runtimepath'--the default setting should work in all but some unusual cases.

If you set 'runtimepath' as you show above, yet you put your SnipMate files under USER/vimfiles/plugin or USER/vimfiles/ftplugin, Vim isn't going to find them.

I would:

1. put configuration settings in _vimrc rather than _gvimrc,
2. not set 'runtimepath',
3. make sure the SnipMate files are where they are supposed to be.

Then if it still doesn't work, execute

```
:scriptnames
```

to see all the runtime files that Vim actually loaded and make sure you put the SnipMate files someplace Vim is looking.

Comment: I tried your approach:
1. removed runtime path
2. config in _vimrc
3. :scriptnames shows it loads plugin/snipmate, ftplugin/snipmate, ftplugin/html_snip_helper, after/plugin/snipmate ...

It seems like it's all loaded correctly, but when I enter 'html' or 'doctype' in a html file an hit TAB nothing happens.

Do I have to map the key? Isn't it done by the script?

It also looks like there are no snippets loaded, shouldnt there be a file like: html.snippets ?

Comment: There is a file, snippets/html.snippets, that should also be read by the SnipMate plugin, but it won't appear in the output of `:scriptnames` because Vim doesn't load it itself. Did you include `filetype plugin on` in your _vimrc? (It looks like you did.) I don't use the snipMate plugin, but I downloaded the zip file from vim.sf.net and installed it in a test directory. I opened foo.html, typed `html`, hit <tab> and got <html> and </html> tags, so it seems to work for me. The script maps tab. What do you see if you execute `:map <tab>`, where `<tab>` is five characters, not a literal tab?

Comment: i get: "s <Tab>     * <Esc>i<Right><C-R>=TriggerSnippet()<CR>"
... yes i included filetype plugin on in my _vimrc .. if i hit tab it only jumps to the next tabstop and doesnt trigger the snippet

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled vim from scratch, added snipMate first and it works.
Curious what caused the problem i started adding the other plugins one by one, now i have all plugins reinstalled and it still works. That leaves me wondering why it didn't work in the first place.

In case I find out what the excact problem was I'll update it here. Thanks for your support garyjohn, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In my case snipMate did not work because of wrong line im .vimrc - the line contains two commas:

`set wildignore+=*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,tmp,,cache`

But I guess I'm the only one in the world who ever experienced it ;-)

Comment: Well I was experiencing it too!  Thanks for the fix!